# Auto Run Script after power on - Raspberry Pi

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, octoprint

I'm a total noob at programming, and therefore ran into a problem while problem solving on my Raspberry Pi.

I have a .sh script on my desktop that I would like to run after my Raspberry Pi is booted. So far, I have tried the following...

First, I go to the terminal and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

From there, I then proceed to add the following line to the end of the 'autostart' script:

```
@! /bin/bash /home/pi/Desktop/MyFile.sh
```

Unfortunately, my code isn't running when I do these steps.

Any ideas/help would be tremendously appreciated!!!

Comment: Take a look at `/etc/rc.local`. Also, check this out: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

You can use crontab to make a script run whenever you want. This can be done at startup or at intervals which you set.

To add an entry to crontab type in terminal

```
crontab -e
```

it will ask which editor you want to use, just use nano is the easiest imo. You can then add a line to the file that looks like the following

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/Desktop/myFile.sh
```

use ctrl+x and hit yes to save the file. This should run your command at startup, if you want to run it in the background you can add a & at the end of that command.

Also, i forgot to mention to make sure the script is executable by using

```
chmod a+x /home/pi/Desktop/myFile.sh
```